# Rails 3.2 precompiled assets 404 error

Tags: apache, nginx, ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline

I'm having an issue with Rails 3.2 and asset pipeline in production.

My environment:

- Deployed via capistrano
- RVM
- REE/Passenger
- Rails 3.2.7
- Apache/Plesk 11

This issue is that all of my assets compiled fine and are on the server in shared/assets/ with a symlink pointing there from public/assets. But I get no styles or JS within my app and navigating to the asset files directly I get "404 Not Found" and "nginx"

Again I'm on an apache server and I've successfully deployed this app on a subdomain with no issues. That server is plesk 9/apache but no RVM.  I'm new to Plesk 11 and have never used nginx so my first thought is this being the issue.

But I'm not willing to rule out RVM at this point either.  Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I find this confusing. Your error message says Nginx, but your environment listing does not mention Nginx; on the other hand, you name-check Apache three times. What daemon, specifically, is listening on port 80? And which server did you install and build Passenger for?

Comment: The issue basically came down to that our server is Apache over top a nginx.  first I'd heard of this, but apparently it helps with security and rendering static content more quickly.

Answer (score 5):

You need to add assets as a location in your nginx server block

```
location ~ ^/(assets)/  {
root /your/root/path/domain.com/current/public;
gzip_static on; # to serve pre-gzipped version
expires max;
add_header  Cache-Control public;
}
```

Comment: I don't find it at all clear that the original poster is using Nginx for Rails.